# Entity Link Access Denied

Tags: 8, entities

I have below content entity:

```
/**
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "test_entity",
 *   label = @Translation("label"),
 *   bundle_label = @Translation("Testing entity type"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "storage" = "Drupal\test_entity\TestEntityStorage",
 *     "storage_schema" = "Drupal\test_entity\TestEntityStorageSchema",
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "access" = "Drupal\test_entity\TestEntityAccessControlHandler",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\test_entity\TestEntityForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\test_entity\TestEntityForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityDeleteForm"
 *     },
 *     "route_provider" = { "html" = "Drupal\test_entity\Entity\TestEntityRouteProvider" },
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\test_entity\TestEntityListBuilder",
 *   },
 *   translatable = FALSE,
 *   entity_keys = { "id" = "id", "bundle" = "type", "label" = "test", "uuid" = "uuid" },
 *   bundle_entity_type = "test_entity_type",
 *   field_ui_base_route = "entity.test_entity_type.edit_form",
 *   common_reference_target = TRUE,
 *   permission_granularity = "bundle",
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/testing/my-entity/{test_entity}",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/testing/my-entity/{test_entity}/delete",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/testing/my-entity/{test_entity}/edit",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/testing/my-entity",
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

and i encounter Access denied for my links below:

```
 /*   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/testing/my-entity/{test_entity}",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/testing/my-entity/{test_entity}/delete",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/testing/my-entity/{test_entity}/edit",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/testing/my-entity",
 */   }
```

where i should start to take a look to troubleshoot this?

Comment: which drupal 8 version you are using.

Comment: @vijay, Im using latest version of Drupal: 8.3.1

Comment: are you tried to create entity by drupal console

Comment: Because I am  see here many difference between your code and drupal console generated entity code.

Comment: Im not using drupal console, it is basically, combination mix of code, sample and reference from others and my own modification. the entire code is quite a lot which i think may not relevant to share in this questions.

Comment: Yeah you are right. But if you compare code then there is lots of difference. Just try to create any dummy entity by drupal console and compare your code with that code. You will understand error immediatly, Here I am seeing your code is not up to date with latest version, because many online articles for create Custom entity is base on version 8.2. So please check with drupal console.

Comment: Even you can take help from drupal core module: E.g: core->modules->user->src->entity->User.php